# How to make Restful API in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, rest, api, codeigniter

I am having problems when trying the API that I made. When I tested it in Postman, it appeared false, even though my username and password were correct. Can you identify the problem with my code? 
I really appreciate your help.

Auth_admin.php

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

require APPPATH . '/libraries/REST_Controller.php';

class Auth_admin extends REST_Controller
{
    public function signin_post()
    {
        $this->load->model('model_admin', 'admin');
        $params = array(
                'username' => $this->post('username'),
                'password' => md5($this->post('password'))  
    );
    $result = $this->admin->admin_check($params);
    if ($result){
        if ($result->level == "admin"){

            $response   = array(
                "status"    => true,
                "message"   => "Authentication seccessfully",
                "auth"      => array(
                    "username"  => $result->username
                )
            );
            $this->set_response($response, REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
        }else{
            $response   = array(
                "status"    => false,
                "message"   => "This features does'nt exist for your Account"
            );
            $this->set_response($response, REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
        }
    }
}
    }
```

Model_admin.php

```
<?php

class Model_admin extends CI_Model
{
    var $tablename;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->tablename    = "m_admin";
    }

    public function admin_check($data = array())
    {
        $params = array(
            'username' => $data['username'],
            'password' => $data['password'],
        );
        $this->db->where($params);
        $query  = $this->db->get($this->tablename);
        return $query->row();
    }

}
```

[image: postman result]

Comment: Please dont __roll your own__ password hashing, specially not using MD5() or SHA1(). 
PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them for the safety of your users. I am sure Codeigniter provides soemthing to do this properly as well

Comment: from img i can see you are calling index function of class Auth_admin which does not exist

Comment: Looks like I'm forgetting something. Thank you for your help. I appreciate that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass function name after the controller name.

Like your path: http://192.168.122.1/project_name/auth_admin/signin it will work.

If that does not work, then please add `index.php` and check it because it depends on how you setup the project.